# Python: How to unit test a custom HTTP request Handler?

Tags: python, unit-testing, simplehttpserver

I have a custom HTTP request handler that can be simplified to something like this:

```py
# Python 3:
from http import server

class MyHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()

        # Here's where all the complicated logic is done to generate HTML.
        # For clarity here, replace with a simple stand-in:
        html = "<html><p>hello world</p></html>"

        self.wfile.write(html.encode())
```

I'd like to unit-test this handler (i.e. make sure that my `do_GET` executes without an exception) without actually starting a web server. Is there any lightweight way to mock the `SimpleHTTPServer` so that I can test this code?

Comment: `import mock` and a little reading should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach I came up with to mock the server. Note that this should be compatible with both Python 2 and python 3. The only issue is that I can't find a way to access the result of the `GET` request, but at least the test will catch any exceptions it comes across!

```
try:
    # Python 2.x
    import BaseHTTPServer as server
    from StringIO import StringIO as IO
except ImportError:
    # Python 3.x
    from http import server
    from io import BytesIO as IO


class MyHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    """Custom handler to be tested"""
    def do_GET(self):
        # print just to confirm that this method is being called
        print("executing do_GET") # just to confirm...

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()

        # Here's where all the complicated logic is done to generate HTML.
        # For clarity here, replace with a simple stand-in:
        html = "<html><p>hello world</p></html>"

        self.wfile.write(html.encode())


def test_handler():
    """Test the custom HTTP request handler by mocking a server"""
    class MockRequest(object):
        def makefile(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return IO(b"GET /")

    class MockServer(object):
        def __init__(self, ip_port, Handler):
            handler = Handler(MockRequest(), ip_port, self)

    # The GET request will be sent here
    # and any exceptions will be propagated through.
    server = MockServer(('0.0.0.0', 8888), MyHandler)


test_handler()
```

Comment: Have you eventually found a way to test the internal functioning of the `do_GET` method?

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on the answer from jakevdp, I managed to be able to check the output, too:

```
try:
    import unittest2 as unittest
except ImportError:
    import unittest
try:
    from io import BytesIO as IO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO as IO
from server import MyHandlerSSL  # My BaseHTTPRequestHandler child


class TestableHandler(MyHandlerSSL):
    # On Python3, in socketserver.StreamRequestHandler, if this is
    # set it will use makefile() to produce the output stream. Otherwise,
    # it will use socketserver._SocketWriter, and we won't be able to get
    # to the data
    wbufsize = 1

    def finish(self):
        # Do not close self.wfile, so we can read its value
        self.wfile.flush()
        self.rfile.close()

    def date_time_string(self, timestamp=None):
        """ Mocked date time string """
        return 'DATETIME'

    def version_string(self):
        """ mock the server id """
        return 'BaseHTTP/x.x Python/x.x.x'


class MockSocket(object):
    def getsockname(self):
        return ('sockname',)


class MockRequest(object):
    _sock = MockSocket()

    def __init__(self, path):
        self._path = path

    def makefile(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args[0] == 'rb':
            return IO(b"GET %s HTTP/1.0" % self._path)
        elif args[0] == 'wb':
            return IO(b'')
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown file type to make", args, kwargs)


class HTTPRequestHandlerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    maxDiff = None

    def _test(self, request):
        handler = TestableHandler(request, (0, 0), None)
        return handler.wfile.getvalue()

    def test_unauthenticated(self):
        self.assertEqual(
                self._test(MockRequest(b'/')),
                b"""HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized\r
Server: BaseHTTP/x.x Python/x.x.x\r
Date: DATETIME\r
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="MyRealm", charset="UTF-8"\r
Content-type: text/html\r
\r
<html><head><title>Authentication Failed</title></html><body><h1>Authentication Failed</h1><p>Authentication Failed. Authorised Personnel Only.</p></body></html>"""
                )


def main():
    unittest.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code I am testing returns a 401 Unauthorised for "/". Change the response as appopriate for your test case.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a little tricky depending on how "deep" you want to go into the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` behavior to define your unit test. At the most basic level I think you can use [this example](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/#quick-guide) from the `mock` library:

```
>>> from mock import MagicMock
>>> thing = ProductionClass()
>>> thing.method = MagicMock(return_value=3)
>>> thing.method(3, 4, 5, key='value')
3
>>> thing.method.assert_called_with(3, 4, 5, key='value')
```

So if you know which methods in the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` your class is going to call you could mock the results of those methods to be something acceptable. This can of course get pretty complex depending on how many different types of server responses you want to test.

Comment: Thanks – I spent a bit playing around with this, but I'm still stuck. Instantiating ``MyHandler`` requires a ``request`` object, and obtaining a ``request`` object seems to require starting a server. I still have not been able to figure out how to create or obtain an instance of ``MyHandler`` without actually starting the server and generating a request. I'll have to spend more time digging through the ``BaseHTTPServer`` source to try to figure out how to mock it...

Comment: Maybe you could try to make a totally mocked `request` object doing something like `old_check_request = request`
then `my_module.request = mock_request` and then create something that behaves as desired.

Comment: Thanks! Check out the possible solution I just posted.